# Replace anchor text with link after click

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

I'm sure this is simple, but I can't seem to get it working.

I'd like to replace an anchor link after the link is clicked. The replaced link will come from a `data-href` value.

Here's the HTML

```
<header class="site-header">
    <nav class="nav-primary">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#services" class="home-nav" data-href="/services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about" class="home-nav" data-href="/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio" class="home-nav" data-href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blog" class="home-nav" data-href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="site-inner">
    <div class="content-site-wrap">
        <section id="services">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</section>
        <section id="about">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</section>
        <section id="portfolio">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</section>
        <section id="blog">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</section>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my attempt at the JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.nav-primary a', function(){
   $('a.home-nav').attr('href', data('href'));
});
```

Not sure if it matters, but I am using jquery's smooth scroll on this page, so when a link from the nav is clicked, it is to scroll to anchor spot on the page. If that same link was clicked, it would then go to the link defined by `data-href`.

Simply put, i just need to replace the `#` of a link after it's clicked. Maybe a simple `replace` function might work.

Comment: <a onclick="this.href=this.getAttribute('data-href');return false;"/>

Comment: @MagicLasso This changed the link's `href`, but on initial click, it didn't jump tot he anchor, and on subsequent clicks it didn't go to the `data-href` defined link.

Comment: Ah so you are wanting to go to the link stored in 'data-href' ?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question to help define what I"m looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Use `$(this).data('href')` instead of `data('href')`

```
$(document).on('click', '.nav-primary a', function(){
   $('a.home-nav').attr('href', $(this).data('href'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this with no go. I did add some more info to the original question. Not sure if there's a conflict with other java that i'm using or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

$(document).on('click', '.nav-primary a', function(){
 console.log($(this).attr('data-href'))
 $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('data-href'));
});
```

DEMO
    http://jsfiddle.net/CkaLx/

Comment: Thanks. I tried this with no go. I did add some more info to the original question. Not sure if there's a conflict with other java that i'm using or not.